# Will LINQ to SQL use defered execution when we map the result to an object?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Will LINQ use defered execution when we map the result to an object?

```
var x = from rcrd in DBContext.FooTable
        select new Model.BOFoo()
        { Bar = rcrd.Bar };
```

The above code map rcrd to Model.BOFoo object. Will this mapping cause LINQ to fetch the actual data from the database? Or will it wait until I call x.ToList()?

Comment: Very nice question, this will solve doubts of few.:)

Answer (score 1):

I'd answer yes. If I don't miss any information about this, LINQ will still use deferred execution even if we map the result to object. The object initialization will also be deferred.

Answer (score 1):

Unless your Linq query includes a method that executes the query, then no, it will not execute and will be deferred.

Examples of methods that execute the query include First(), FirstOrDefault(), ToList(), ToArray, etc..

select is not such a method, not even select new.

Answer (score 0):

I always find it useful to think of the code as it would be in a method chain:

```
DBContext.FooTable
  .Select(rcrd=>new Model.BOFoo{Bar=rcrd.Bar});
```

Here it is easier to visualize the deferred execution as you are only passing a function into the `Select` that will be evaluated as needed. The `new` is merely a part of that function.

So, as har07 and Erik already mentioned, if it is a deferred execution method, then it will remain that way unless forced via another method such as `ToList`